# Include Project Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

How can I **include** my **Projects** in gradle ?,

I want to build **Debug, Framework, Processors , Utils**

I'm completely new to Gradle, but have tried the following in my build.gradle within MyProject.

My Tree Directory :

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── dirctorySub
│   ├── Debug
│   │   └── app
│   │       ├── build.gradle
│   │       └── src
│   │           └── main
│   │               ├── java
│   │               │   └── debug
│   │               │       └── debug.java
│   │               └── resources
│   ├── Framework
│   │   └── app
│   │       ├── build.gradle
│   │       └── src
│   │           └── main
│   │               ├── java
│   │               │   └── dirctorySub
│   │               │       └── dirctorySub.java
│   │               └── resources
│   ├── Processors
│   │   └── app
│   │       ├── build.gradle
│   │       └── src
│   │           └── main
│   │               ├── java
│   │               │   └── x86
│   │               │       └── x86.java
│   │               └── resources
│   └── Utils
│       └── app
│           ├── build.gradle
│           └── src
│               └── main
│                   ├── java
│                   │   └── Utils
│                   │       └── utils.java
│                   └── resources
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

My settings.gradle looks

```
rootProject.name = 'dirctorySub'
include('dirctorySub/Debug', 'dirctorySub/Framework', 'dirctorySub/Processors', 'dirctorySub/Utils')
```

But it throws : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I catch an error like this :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':dirctorySub/Debug/app'.
> The project name 'dirctorySub/Debug/app' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement (see https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for more details).
```

Comment: Try add `build.gradle` file in root sub-module folder example `directorySub/Debug/build.gradle` or include `directorySub/Debug/app` in your settings...

Comment: `But it throws : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.` What's the exception? What's in `./build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for any **gradle** project I found answer to my question on this link

> https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/gradle/support/settingsUtil.gradle

I change my rootProject **settings.gradle**

```
apply from: "gradle/support/settingsUtil.gradle"
rootProject.name = 'dirctorySub'

includeProjects('dirctorySub/Debug')
includeProjects('dirctorySub/Framework')
includeProjects('dirctorySub/Processors')
includeProjects('dirctorySub/Utils')
```

Credit to NationalSecurityAgency : https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra